# Input dentro de DIV com visibility:hidden

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Galera é o seguinte, ocultei umas `div`,que possuem inputs de um formulário dentro, com

```
style='visibility:hidden; position:absolute'
```

E gostaria que essas `DIV` não enviassem informação quando o formulário fosse encaminhado.

A minha questão é: Só tem como fazer isso usando JS ou existe uma forma mais simples e menos braçal pra fazer isso?

Comment: O máximo que você pode fazer é agrupar inputs usando um `fieldset` ao invés de uma `div` e marcar este `fieldset` com a property `disabled`, infelizmente esta abordagem não funciona no IE.

Comment: @TobyMosque acabei de testá-la e realmente não funciona no IE

Answer (score 1):

para ocultar campos de um formulário use

```
<input type="hidden" name="NomeDoInput">
```

Ao invés de fazer isso via CSS.
caso não queira que os dados de um formulario não sejam enviado para outra pagina usando `form`, deixe esses inputs fora do form ou se preferir use:

```
unset($_POST['nomeDoCampo']); //Com PHP
```

caso esses dados já tenham sido enviados.

Comment: +1 Concordo que a melhor forma de não enviar os inputs com o form seja, justamente, deixá-los fora deste.

Comment: A pagina dele pode ser feita em ASP.NET WebForms com o form1 na MasterPage, a visibilidade da div pode está sendo controlada por algum script, alem de outros fatores que podem inviabilizar de colocar os inputs fora do form. Em todo caso esta resposta não responde a pergunta, "como impedir o envio de um input através de alguma marcação em um parent".

Comment: A questão é justamente essa que @TobyMosque disse. Está sendo controlada por um script, existe a necessidade de deixar os inputs dentro do form.

Comment: Por favor especifique a linguagem que esta usando, deixar HTML e CSS abre muitas possíveis opções usando diversas outras linguagens.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly alterei lá, to usando php + javascript.

Comment: quando o parâmetro for passado pelo form para a outra pagina tente usar unset($_POST['seuCampo']) para que ele deixe de "existir", já tentou isso?

Comment: atualmente estou utilizando essa solução, mas estou procurando encontrar uma forma menos braçal, como essa.